# fseek error with LONG_MAX

Tags: c++, c, file-io

I'm trying to use fseek to step through a very large (~500 GB) file. Since fseek's second parameter, the offset, is a long int, I have to account for when the offset I want is greater than 2^31 - 1. Here's my solution:

```
    fseek(file,offset % LONG_MAX,SEEK_SET);;
    for (int i = 0; i < offset/LONG_MAX; i++)
    {
      fseek(file,LONG_MAX,SEEK_CUR);
    }
```

Where LONG_MAX is defined in limits.h and offset is a 64 bit int. However, there is an error with the fseek call within the for loop. It returns a nonzero value, and perror says "Invalid argument". Why can't I use LONG_MAX (defined as 2147483647L) as an offset?

Comment: Are you sure it is? Here LONG_MAX is defined to be 9223372036854775807

Comment: what OS? You may need to specifically use 64bit versions of fseek, eg _fseeki64 to access files > 4Gb

Comment: Yeah, the program only enters the for loop when offset > 2^31 - 1. Also, my IDE says that LONG_MAX is defined as 2147483647L.

Comment: It might help to `printf()` the values of `offset % LONG_MAX`, `LONG_MAX`, and `i` to make sure what you're assuming to be true actually is... Most "modern" OSes that handle large files (i.e. 4GB and greater) have `offset_t` as a 64-bit integer, even if the underlying platform is still 32-bit.

Comment: You probably want to read up on Large File Support (LFS) : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_file_support . How to enable/use it will depend on your specific os.

Comment: You might want to show us the output of strace (or similar tool) for the specific syscall.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a "normal" OS, use the fseek64() variant.

Comment: That does solve the problem, but I was looking for a solution that is compiler independent. I'll use the fseek64() version for now, but I would like to know why I can't use LONG_MAX as an offset to fseek()

Comment: @Durn : it's not really that you try to seek using `LONG_MAX` as an offset - it's that you're trying to seek beyond the capabilities of the `fseek` function. You were trying to make the `fseek` function do something it wasn't made for, and this is its way of telling you off.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the error is Long_Max ?! If that's your original code, maybe it's the difference between 'file' & 'file_' in the two fseek fns ?!

Comment: Sorry, I edited my code before posting it because some of the variable names woudn't make sense out of context. So yeah, it's not due to the different file IDs.